# I hope it's possible to access the elements of this site. http://listenonrepeat.com/

Tags: web

I really have the feeling it's possible to access the elements of this site http://listenonrepeat.com/watch/?v=99j0zLuNhi8#Creed_-_With_Arms_Wide_Open. I'm experimenting to make keyboard shortcuts to the site. I wanna **access/control** the play/pause button and this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0wsJ.png **While** I'm in another tabs or I'm not there in thelistenonrepeat.com site. If it is possible, could you please tell it to me how? I know some web languages (javascript and html). THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the source code of the site reveals that `PLAYER.player` is a reference to the YouTube player object, which is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). In short you can use JavaScript methods like `PLAYER.player.playVideo()` to control the video. As for executing those functions while you're in another tab, I don't know. There may be browser extensions that let you do that.

Comment: what specific keyword should I find?

Comment: Shortcut Manager for Chrome looks like a start, though it's not perfect. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf
I really don't know. I searched for "javascript keyboard shortcut extension" but I didn't find a lot.